# stored procedure select query call from spring boot jdbc template

Tags: java, postgresql

i want to display the stored procedure select query data as table in pgadmin
I want to display the stored procedure select query output through the java spring boot app by using JDBC template.
I can do this by using stored function in Postgres but not able to do it through stored procedure of postgres.
here my procedure is created and called it is working but my table data is not displaying out in pgadmin

**stored procedure**
CREATE PROCEDURE get_mobiles(brand_name varchar)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
SELECT * FROM mobile_phone where brand_name = brand_name;
$$;

can we able to display the select query procedure output in postgres pgadmin without function, if yes means how? and how can feed these inputs to my JDBC template

Answer (score 0):

With your current code there is no way to display the query output. You have a couple of issues.

1. In order to return those results you would need to define an OUT parameter to hold those results. You have no OUT parameter.
2. Your where clause is effective `where 1=1`.  In SQL when a object name matches a column name and there is no further qualification that name **always** applies the the table column. Since your parameter name in the same as the column name it always matches. This is very very bad parameter naming; Always prefix or suffix the parameter name or qualify it with the procedure name (so here `where brand_name=get_mobiles.brand_name`).
3. Finally while a *procedure* can be used this should be a ***function*** instead.

Further this can be done in a single SQL statement so need for plpgsql at all; just use *language sql*. So: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/XU_1YjtY) here.)

```
create or replace function get_mobiles(brand_name_in varchar)
  returns mobile_phones
 language sql 
as $$
    select * 
      from mobile_phones 
     where brand_name = brand_name_in;
$$;
```

Notice the use of the *table name* as the data type. Actually it is not the table itself. When Postgres creates a table it also created a type of the same name, it is that type which is referenced.

**NOTE:** Demo includes how it is done with a Procedure. Unfortunately *db<>fiddle* does not show the `raise notice ...` messages. You will have to run the procedure/do on your own.